# Meteor App hangs when adding Ecmascript

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

I recently updated my Meteor App to 1.3 and also want to migrate to the "new style" of coding, meaning ES2015, React, later on Apollo/GraphQL.

First I only want to use the import syntax. But when I *meteor add Ecmascript* it will then hang on *meteor*:
*Building for web.browser                  /*
takes forever.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case this is how I got it fixed. May be it is the same for you.

> I had multiple third party libraries in client/lib folder.

To use ES6 syntax, I added 'ecmascript' to my .meteor/packages file and after that issuing the meteor command would just hang.
During trial and error, I figured out that

> deleting the client/lib directory made meteor to start

.
For the libraries my application depends on, I went to https://atmospherejs.com, searched for the meteor specific package name for the dependency and added these to `.meteor/packages` file.

e.g: Instead of copying the datatables.js and datatables.css inside client/lib folder, add 'menway:jquery-datatables' to .meteor/packages or issue the command `meteor add menway:jquery-datatables`

Comment: This could be the cause. Have to try this out when I got the time. Actually, we use a lot of libraries directly (like momentjs etc.). I will comment then.